# Consulta á base de dados através de uma text box

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, datagridview

Olá, neste momento estou numa parte de um projeto onde tenho que fazer uma pesquisa à base de dados através de uma text box.
Por exemplo pesquisava por"José" e retornava-me todos os dados contidos na base de dados com o nome "José". Também poderia pesquisar por "Rua da Travessia" por exemplo.
O objetivo é que depois da consulta os resultado apareçam num datagridview
Sou muito inexperiente em SQL e agradecia a vossa ajuda.
Obrigado.
Cumprimentos.

Comment: Veja como fazer o Retrieving de dados primeiro, e com isso ja deve perceber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para realizar a consulta enquanto o usuário digita no textBox, eu utilizo o evento TextChanged associado a um timer, que irá executar quando o usuário para de digitar.

Na parte do Sql, basta você definir em quais colunas será pesquisado o valor que digitou no textBox, e utilizar OR entre elas.

Fiz um código básico para te exemplificar:

```
 public partial class FormConsulta : Form
    {
        public FormConsulta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 400;
        }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ao alterar o texto do TextBox, reseta o timer
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ao disparar o envento do timer, executa a consulta
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Consultar();
    }

    private void Consultar()
    {
        //Executa consulta e define o datasource do gridview
        string sql = @"select * from tabela where upper(nome) like '%"+textBox1.Text.ToUpper()+"%' or upper(endereco) like '%"+textBox1.Text.ToUpper()+"%';";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("sua string de conexao");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
}
```

Na parte do comando SQL, prefira utilizar parâmetros, e não concatenar diretamente na string, como fiz no exemplo.

E para comparação de Textos, como você precisa, utilize o operador LIKE, caso contrário o conteúdo da coluna que está pesquisando deverá ser exatamente igual ao digitado no textBox pelo usuário.

Mais informação sobre o LIKE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179859.aspx